# Configuring A Preflight Channel

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, coldfusion, cors

I've run into an issue when POSTing to an external API. The error is always:

```
Reason: missing token ‘content-type’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel
```

After some research I've come to understand that a preflight request originates from my server, and is essentially making sure everything looks good before making the actual CORS request.

So I set out on a quest to change my Access-Control-Allow-Headers to allow sending a `Content-Type` header but I have no clue what I'm doing. I'm not a very confident back end developer and I'm not confident in coldfusion, basically using it as a bridge between JS and MySQL and that's it.

I've found a few files that looked promising, namely a file called `web.config` and a file called `crossdomain.xml` in the root of the application.

I first tried to edit `web.config` which was initially:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

Which I edited to:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Header" value="Content-Type" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But this didn't fix the problem. I also tried to edit the spelling in case it was case sensitive but no luck.

So then I tried to edit `crossdomain.xml` which seemed promising, it was initially:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

So I tried changing it to:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="api.com" headers="Content-type"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

But that also did nothing. I'm worried that since these were empty rulesets that they are being ignored by the server, and that means there must be some other file but I've been looking at random files on the server for an hour now and can't find anything else that seems to handle CORs or Access-Control.

This is an EC2 instance but from my understanding I can't set these via AWS, I need to set them on my server? I'm genuinely uncertain and very confused. Any explanation or further reading you could provide me with would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using on your server? Please elaborate the content of the server.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Like I said I barely understand what I'm doing here. I think it's NGINX if thats what you're asking but idk how to find that out. I didn't set this up and the guy who did is long gone

Comment: Allright, do you see any .htaccess file? It should be located in the source code (public_html/your_folder) directory. Please check it then I might have few suggestion.

Comment: If you are posting to an "external API" (as in, 3rd party, not something your server) then the problem is with the external API or something about the way you are using it -- not something on *your* web server.  Perhaps I am not understanding what "external" means, here.